# Nested templated class: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, class, templates, nvcc

Using MSVC++ 2010 (NVCC (CUDA) compiler), defining a **nested templated** class member of a **non-templated parent** class outside its declaration block:

```
class cls {
public:
    template <typename V> class nest {
    public:
        template <typename W> void bar(W x);
    };
};

template <typename V>
template <typename W>
void cls::nest<V>::bar(W x) {}
```

yields:

```
error C2244: 'bar' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
1>          definition
1>          'void cls::nest<V>::bar(W)'
1>          existing declarations
1>          'void cls::nest<V>::bar(W)'
```

why?

**Update**: appears to be an NVCC bug. http://ideone.com/rc7R32 works, but not with NVCC. Anyone from Nvidia around to comment?

Comment: Mine compiles I'm not sure what the error your getting is

Comment: MSVC probably has a bug, I used clang, g++ also works, this isn't cuda but I also just compiled it with nvcc

Comment: compiling as strict as it gets with `g++ -c -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c++98`  gives no warnings or errors.  MSVC is dumb

Comment: Indeed http://ideone.com/rc7R32 works, but fails with NVCC. Putting it down to Nvidia bug.